# Arrow Key Navigation in a WPF Form is Odd

Tags: wpf, arrow-keys

I have a WPF form with which I would like to have arrow-key navigation.  The current system is off, even though I have successfully specified the tab navigation order.  I have two rows of three radio buttons.  When I am on the middle button, top row, I should be able to hit the left arrow and select the first button of the top row; instead it selects the first button, bottom row.  How do I correct this?

### Update:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="15*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="30*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="25*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="Who:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0" FontSize="12"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Caller:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Content="Office:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Content="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Content="Find" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="50" Command="{Binding Path=FindCommand}" IsDefault="True" Click="Button_Click" TabIndex="9" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <RadioButton Content="All People" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsPersonAll}" TabIndex="3" />
        <RadioButton Content="Users Only" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsPersonUser}" TabIndex="4" />
        <RadioButton Content="Admin Only" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="5" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <RadioButton Content="Off Campus" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCallerOff}" TabIndex="6" />
        <RadioButton Content="Admin" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCallerOnAd}" TabIndex="7" />
        <RadioButton Content="User" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="8" />
    </Grid>
    <ComboBox 
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" 
        Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Offices}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Office}" TabIndex="2" />
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="55*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="45*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Name="lName" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="22" Text="{Binding Path=LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TabIndex="0" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="22" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TabIndex="1" />
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Content="Last Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-5,-5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="First Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,-5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Please supply search information in Department or Name." Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-5,-5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="26" Visibility="{Binding Path=ErrVisibility}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Tabindex shouldn't affect arrow key navigation, it rather navigates through the children of the layout container. Are you using a single grid (2 rows / 3 columns) hosting the radio buttons? Maybe provide the XAML

Comment: @milter -- thanks, here's the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's also for me kind of odd behaviour and after playing around with it i can tell you that it's caused by the HorizontalAlignment property, but i can't really explain why. Maybe someone else can shed some light on that.

---

Some more information:

In your case controls are focused alphabetically by the content property. You can easily test that by changing

```
<RadioButton Content="All People" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
```

to

```
<RadioButton Content="Pall People" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
```

After changing, controls are now focused correctly from right to left on first line because of alphabetical order: Users -> Pall People -> Off Campus.

As i was not aware of this behaviour i tried to reproduce by creating a new project with following XAML, but the behaviour of arrow keys was as expected, focusing the next neigbour in direction of the arrow key:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="All People"></RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" Content="Users Only"></RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Content="Admin Only"></RadioButton>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <RadioButton Grid.Column="0" Content="Off Campus"></RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Grid.Column="1" Content="Admin"></RadioButton>
            <RadioButton Grid.Column="2" Content="User"></RadioButton>
        </Grid>
</Grid>
```

So i removed properties of the radio buttons of your xaml till i finally hit the point by removing HorizontalAlignment.

That XAML is now working as expected, at least for the radio buttons:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <RadioButton Content="All People" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsPersonAll}" TabIndex="3" />
    <RadioButton Content="Users Only" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsPersonUser}" TabIndex="4" />
    <RadioButton Content="Admin Only" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="5" />
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <RadioButton Content="Off Campus" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCallerOff}" TabIndex="6" />
    <RadioButton Content="Admin" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsCallerOnAd}" TabIndex="7" />
    <RadioButton Content="User" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" TabIndex="8" />
</Grid>
```